# How would I store values in a different array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I want to store non "h" values in an array. So to give you a background, I need to make a basic cash register that accepts 5 items in an array with a price on them. Nevertheless, some items will have HST(tax) included with them. To know which items have tax and which don't. The user will press h or H before or after entering the dollar amount. I have stored the values with the HST in an array, but how would I store the non-HST values?

**NOTE**: I tried doing it as the same as my "h" values, but it would not work that's why I am confused

**I cannot use Arrayslist or any other array methods**

Sample input:

```
4.565H
H2.3435
4.565h
5.234
5.6576h
```

Sample Output:

```
HST Values:
4.565
2.3435
4.565
5.6576

Non-HST Values
5.234
```

---

My Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create scanner object and set scanner variables
        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Press any key to start");
        String key = inp.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\nEnter the amount of each item");
        System.out.println("Up to 5 inputs are allowed!\n");

        // Initialize counter and index variables to use it in the while loop
        int counter = 0;
        int index = 0;
 
        // Create a double array variable, and set the limit to 5
        double[] numbers = new double[5];

        // Create a boolean variable to use it in the while loop
        boolean go = true;

        while (go) {           
            String value = inp.nextLine();      
            value = value.toLowerCase();
  
            // Set the index value to "h" or "H"
            int indexOfh = value.indexOf('h');

            boolean containsh = (indexOfh == 0 || indexOfh == value.length() - 1);
            
            if (containsh) { //Validate h at beginning or end
                numbers[index] = Double.parseDouble(value.replace("h", ""));
                index++;
                System.out.println("HST will be taken account for this value");
            }

            counter++;
            if (counter == 5) {
                go = false;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("HST Values:");
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(numbers[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first select the inputs that have "H" or "h" with [contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)).

Then you can use [replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to replace "h" or "h" with the empty String "". You can use the regex "[hH]" to target both upper- and lower-case. You can look at how to define a set of characters for regexes [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).